# Easy way to search values with dash (-) and space seperated in SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Hi i have many record in my db as

```
- above the line...
- above-the line...
- above-the-line...
- above the-line...
```

I want to query them with like query

```
Select words.* from words where sentence ILIKE 'above the line%';
```

But this query naturaly gets only first result.

Is there a easy way for ignoring dash without using OR with every possibilities?

Comment: You can always use full regular expressions with the `~` operator.

Comment: @yes... you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underscore is a wild card in sql, so try 'above_the_line'.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as :

```
Word.where("sentence ~* ?", '^above[- ]the[- ]line').all
```